# Is using frequent irregular sentences acceptable in writing books?

Tags: grammaticality

I am editing a friend's story, and he constantly has sentences with no verbs or subjects, which he defends as being an accepted literary style.  I'm not bothered by one or two, but every page seems to have one.  As if they add something.  And nothing more.  Which just seems choppy. But could add to the spook value?

Within 37 pages, there have been a minimum of 20 sentences in that style, and while a few of them "work" for me, most of them just seem contrived.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is really literary criticism, which is off-topic. In any event I think I would need to read a page or two of his work before expressing an opinion here.

Comment: Bear in mind that this sort of usage may be a literary device if it is associated with the speech pattern of certain characters. Such characters may be angry (and hence speak in a staccato manner), scatter-brained or have a speech impediment, etc. In any case, if the story is in a "stream of consciousness" style, one can expect that grammatical rules will be broken regularly.

Comment: Discussions on writing style like this really belong on [writers.se] instead.

Comment: Catchy and immediate—not. Advertorially fragmentary. Sadder but wiser. Or just incoherent?

Answer (score 1):

If you are troubled by the writer's violations of language norms, you should stop worrying about it. "Correcting" these irregular sentences would be about as appropriate as "correcting" an e.e. cummings poem by adding capital letters to it. Creative writing uses words and sentences as tools to create an effect, in the same way that a painter uses paints and canvas. Sometimes that means writing in a way that wouldn't be considered acceptable in a school or business setting. But there's nothing wrong with that.

If your concern is more that the effect seems contrived, then it's appropriate to discuss that with the writer; changing it yourself without consultation might be taken as presumptuous. You should see your "editor" role as being that of a literary assistant and critic, rather than a direct copy editor and proofreader.

Comment: Thank you, phenry!  I wasn't changing anything but mis-spelled words, but had wanted to find a way to approach the author about them.  In general, I am enjoying his story and the use of incomplete sentences seems acceptable.  He uses them to create a kind of spookiness in the story, and I like the effect.  But within two pages there are, "At least in this state." "Grandma's bedtime stories." "Many of them here, today." "Perhaps thanks to a takeover."  and "The arrangement reminding him of his mother."  I'm searching for a way to tell him that using so many of them is distracting?

Comment: @BarbaraWeaver Mark the "sentences" that seem distracting. If they're distracting because he used them too close together, then mark them as such. I'm assuming your author would appreciate you marking distracting repetitions in words; this is basically the same thing. _If it pulls you out of the story, it's not effective writing._